# How to create relationship between two tables in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am new to cypher/neo4j and I have two tables, "site" and "visit",that have already been loaded into neo4j with the correct data types. The "site" table contains a primary key called "id". The "visit" table contains a primary key, "id", and a foreign key to the "site" table named "site_id". I want to create a relationship between those keys. Here is what I have tried:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///site.csv' AS row
MATCH (v:visit {site_id: row.site_id}), (s:site {id: row.id})
MERGE (s)-[rel:visited {site_id:row.id}] ->(v)
RETURN count(rel)
```

and

```
MATCH (s:site), (v:visit)
WHERE s.id = id AND v.id = site_id
CREATE (s)-[r:visited] ->(v)
RETURN count(r)
```

ERROR: "Variable `id` not defined (line 2, column 14 (offset: 39))
"WHERE s.id = id AND v.id = site_id""

AND

```
MATCH (v:visit {site_id:v.site_id})
MATCH (s:site {id:s.id})
MERGE (v) - [:visited] ->(s)
return s
```

This query: "Java heap space" error.

The site table contains 7,963 unique sites (id) and the visit table contains 18,513 visits. Is this big enough tables to render that error by simply creating a relationship between the table (id) and the visits (site_id)?

I am still a bit confused about the structure of cypher and I am thinking my MERGE statement is incorrect. When I run this the count(rel) returns nothing and no relationship is created. Why is the relationship not being created and what exactly is the MERGE statement doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query has a logical error:

```
MATCH (v:visit {site_id:v.site_id}) <-- This line is erroneous
MATCH (s:site {id:s.id}) <-- This too
MERGE (v) - [:visited] ->(s)
return s
```

You are trying to match `site` with `id` where `s` itself is not computed yet. That's why it is going into error, the same goes for visits. If your data of `site` and `visits` is already loaded, try this:

```
MATCH (s:site)
MATCH (v:visit {site_id:s.id})
MERGE (v)-[:visited] ->(s)
return s
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. So in human speak you script says: "give me the site table, then match the visit table when v.site_id is equal to s.id, then create relationship of visited"? Now a follow up question, if I wanted to add a condition of creating a relationship where site is considered "suitable" that would be incorporated in the merge statement? visit_status is a property key and has values of "suitable", "dry", etc

Comment: No that will be in match clause, you will only fetch nodes, that match your conditions and then create relationships

Comment: got it. thank you clarifying this